# Problema com Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Tenho um `datepiker` porém não está funcionado de maneira correta bom se eu clico no `input` ele funciona legal, porém quando clico na imagem do calendário ele nem passa o valor e também não recebe o que esta no `input`:

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Html:

```
 <div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
        <label for="startDatePicker">Data Início</label>
           <span class="input-type-text">
               <input type="text" id="startDatePicker"  name="startDatePicker" class="datePicker hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Início" />
               <a class="calendar-icon with-tip" href="#" id="IconStartDate" title="Calendário">
                 <img src="~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16">
               </a>
              </span>
</div>
<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
    <label for="endDatePicker">Data Fim</label>
       <span class="input-type-text">
         <input type="text" id="endDatePicker"  name="endDatePicker" class="hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Fim" />
           <a class="calendar-icon with-tip" href="#"  id="IconEndDate" title="Calendário">
            <img  src="~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
          </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startDatePicker").datepick();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepick();
    $("#IconStartDate").datepick();
    $("#IconEndDate").datepick();

    $("#closeModal").live("click", function () {
        $.modal.current.closeModal();
    });
});
```

Olha como está diferente o do input text e o calendário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual plugin de datepicker é esse?

Comment: De preferência, tente montar um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) pra facilitar na resposta.

Comment: Eu perguntei porque está estranho a maneira como você chamou o método, usando `.datepick()` ao invés de `.datepicker()`.

Comment: Como eu disse, tente reproduzir o seu problema em um fiddle onde ocorra esse comportamento. Porque pra mim, utilizando o exemplo padrão funciona corretamente. Pode ser algum conflito com outro código ou plugin que você utiliza.

Comment: Se isso não for `jquery-ui`, diga que plugin é. Se for, a chamada está errada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `datepicker` trabalha **por padrão** em cima do `input` então ao invés de colocá-lo na imagem você pode só dar o foco no campo input.

Outra forma de resolver é utilizando as propriedades do datepicker:

[ShowOn](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn) -
Define quando o calendário deve aparecer, no foco do campo, no clique de um botão ou em ambos.

[buttonImage](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage) - Recebe a URL de uma imagem para exibir o calendário quando a propriedade `ShowOn` está como `Both` ou `Button`.

[buttonImageOnly](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage)  - Define se a imagem do botão deve ser renderizada por si mesma, em vez de dentro de um elemento `button` essa propriedade só é valida se utilizado a propriedade `buttonImage`.

Exemplo com propriedades:

```
$( "#startDatePicker" ).datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png",
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonText: "Selecione a data"
});
```

Exemplo alterando o foco:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker();
    $("#IconStartDate").on("click", function(){
      $("#startDatePicker").focus();
    })
    $("#IconEndDate").on("click", function(){
      $("#endDatePicker").focus();
    })

    $("#closeModal").on("click", function () {
        $.modal.current.closeModal();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
        <label for="startDatePicker">Data Início</label>
           <span class="input-type-text">
               <input type="text" id="startDatePicker"  name="startDatePicker" class="datePicker hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Início" />
               <a class="calendar-icon with-tip datePickerIcon" href="#" id="IconStartDate" title="Calendário">
                 <img src="~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16" alt="icon">
               </a>
              </span>
</div>
<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
    <label for="endDatePicker">Data Fim</label>
       <span class="input-type-text">
         <input type="text" id="endDatePicker"  name="endDatePicker" class="datePicker hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Fim" />
           <a class="calendar-icon with-tip datePickerIcon" href="#"  id="IconEndDate" title="Calendário">
            <img  src="~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" alt="icon" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
          </span>
</div>
```

Mais informações : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: funcionou mas ficou sem o css

Comment: Deu certo so tive que troca o  $(".datePicker").datepicker(); para  $(".datePicker").datepick();

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma outra maneira além da sugerida pelo @Caique Romero, que seria utilizar a opção `showOn`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datePicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
  <label for="startDatePicker">Data Início</label>
  <span class="input-type-text">
               <input type="text" id="startDatePicker"  name="startDatePicker" class="datePicker hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Início" />
              </span>
</div>
<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
  <label for="endDatePicker">Data Fim</label>
  <span class="input-type-text">
         <input type="text" id="endDatePicker"  name="endDatePicker" class="datePicker hasDatePick" placeholder="Data Fim" />
          </span>
</div>
```

Segue o link: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: upvote, não sabia dessa propriedade, vou melhorar minha resposta

Comment: Sua resposta foi outra maneira de resolver também, acho que está bom. Só postei pra mostrar outra solução.